# jQuery checkbox filter, working but want to reset when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I'm building a filter for a selection of condos. I've figured out how to filter using a slider and now also need to filter by number of bedrooms using two checkboxes.

```
<form name="filter" method="post" action="">
  <p>Bedrooms
    <input id="1bdrm" type="checkbox" value="1bdrm" />1 Bedroom
    <input id="2bdrm" type="checkbox" value="2bdrm" />2 Bedroom
  </p>
</form>
```

So far I have the filter limiting the selection to show only 1 bedroom units, but can't figure out how to reset and show all units when unchecking the checkbox.

```
// Set values for units
$('#cohen').data({
  id: 4,
  sqft: 976,
  bdrms: 2
});
$('#curnoe').data({
  id: 5,
  sqft: 572,
  bdrms: 2
});
$('#richler').data({
  id: 6,
  sqft: 624,
  bdrms: 2
});
$('#carr').data({
  id: 7,
  sqft: 544,
  bdrms: 1
});
$('#lawrence').data({
  id: 10,
  sqft: 467,
  bdrms: 1
});

//filter by number of bedrooms
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theValue;

  $("#1bdrm").click(function() {
    filterItems();
  });
});

function filterItems() {
  $.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
    $this = $(this);
    itemData = $this.data();
    if (itemData.bdrms == 1) {
      $this.show();
      itemData.matching = true;
    } else {
      $this.hide();
      itemData.matching = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a fiddle link.. https://jsfiddle.net/3y9vz1q1/ I'm using the .data method to store unique attributes on each unit so that i can filter for each attribute (example: I have another script written for a slider that limits condos by sqft.

Hoping the community can point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance.

Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are marking elements that have the data tag `bdrms` set to 1 as invisible. This does not change. So once they are invisible, they will remain that way.

There are several ways to solve this, one being a seperate function that's being called when the checkbox isn't checked:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    filterItems();
} else {
    resetAll();
}
```

After that it's a simple matter of writing a function that resets the invisble elements back to visible:

```
function resetAll()
{
    $.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(":hidden")){
            $this.show();
        }
    });
}
```

So updating your fiddle would be: https://jsfiddle.net/3y9vz1q1/1/ Which works fine.

**UPDATE:**

A far better solution would be to make both checkboxes work and use a single function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#1bdrm, #2bdrm").click(function() {
    var bdrm1 = false;
    var bdrm2 = false;
    if($("#1bdrm").is(':checked')){
        bdrm1 = true;
    }
    if($("#2bdrm").is(':checked')){
        bdrm2 = true;
    }

    filterItems(bdrm1, bdrm2);
  });
});

function filterItems(bdrm1, bdrm2){
    $.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
    $this = $(this);
    itemData = $this.data();
    if(bdrm1 && !bdrm2){
      if(itemData.bdrms == 1){
        $this.show();
        itemData.matching = true;
      } else {
        $this.hide();
        itemData.matching = false;
      }
    }
    else if(bdrm2 && !bdrm1){
      if(itemData.bdrms == 2){
        $this.show();
        itemData.matching = true;
      } else {
        $this.hide();
        itemData.matching = false;
      }
    } else {
        $this.show();
        itemData.matching = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Fiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/3y9vz1q1/2/

Comment: works as advertised! It was the   .is(':checked') method i was missing! I tried variations of   (#1bdrm :checkbox:checked) with no success. thank you!

Comment: @Marc You're welcome. This would be a far better solution though: https://jsfiddle.net/3y9vz1q1/2/ I've updated it. Now it only uses one function and both checkboxes work.

Comment: I was just sitting down to figure this out! I'm still learning and just reviewing your solutions has helped out a lot. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Always, when you click to checkbox, filter funtion started and because last item

```
$('#lawrence').data({
  id: 10,
  sqft: 467,
  bdrms: 1
});
```

has 1, list don't reset

Try it:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var theValue;

        $("#1bdrm").click(function() {
          if(this.checked){
            filterItems(false);
              }else{
            filterItems(true);
            }
        });
      });

      function filterItems(reset)
      {
        $.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
          $this = $(this);
          itemData = $this.data();
          if(itemData.bdrms == 1 || reset === true){
            $this.show();
            itemData.matching = true;
          } else {
            $this.hide();
            itemData.matching = false;
          }
        });
      }
```