# jQuery multi-faceted filter issue.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I'm building a simple faceted filter to help users find the right condo. A few days ago I got a basic slider to filter out condos by square footage. The next part was getting the checkboxes to work which I posted to SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274928/jquery-checkbox-filter-working-but-want-to-reset-when-unchecked) and got some help from icecub. Since then I've been working on getting them to work in tandem (for example, checking 2 bedrooms and sliding the slider down to 800 sqft filters the condos by both variables). Got this to work yesterday.

The only issue I'm having is that now the slider only works when one of the two checkbox's are checked. If both or none are checked the slider doesn't work. I'm not sure exactly where my logic is flawed.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/baskinco/mwqkztn8/

and here's the JS

```
      // FUNCTIONS
      //make slider textbox equal to slider value
      function printValue(sliderID, textbox) {
        var x = document.getElementById(textbox);
        var y = document.getElementById(sliderID);
        x.value = y.value;
      }

      //get bdrm and slider values
      function getValues() {
        var bdrm1 = false;
        var bdrm2 = false;
        var sliderValue;

        if($("#1bdrm").is(':checked')){
          bdrm1 = true;
        }
        if ($("#2bdrm").is(':checked')){
          bdrm2 = true;
        }
        sliderValue = $("#rangeValue").val();

        runFilter(bdrm1, bdrm2, sliderValue);
      }

      function runFilter(bdrm1, bdrm2, sliderValue) {
        $.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
          $this = $(this);
          condoData = $this.data();
          if(bdrm1 && !bdrm2){
            if ((condoData.bdrms == 1) && (condoData.sqft <= sliderValue)){
              $this.show();
            } else {
              $this.hide();
            }
          } else if(bdrm2 && !bdrm1){
            if ((condoData.bdrms == 2) && (condoData.sqft <= sliderValue)){
              $this.show();
            } else {
              $this.hide();
            }
          } else {
            $this.show();
          }
        });
      }

      // Set values for units
      $('#jackson').data({ 
         id:1, 
         sqft:897, 
         bdrms:2 
      });
      $('#nicholl').data({ 
         id:2, 
         sqft:808, 
         bdrms:2 
      });
      $('#atwood').data({ 
         id:3, 
         sqft:1020, 
         bdrms:2 
      });
      //etc

    //MAIN SCRIPT
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //print slider value to slider textbox
        printValue('slider','rangeValue');

        //when a bdrm box is checked ..
        $("#1bdrm, #2bdrm").click(function(){
          getValues();
        });

        //when the slider is moved
        $("#slider").change(function() {
          getValues();
        });
      });
```

Comment: if your markup isn't changing much, it is good practice to cache selectors in variables. It can be costly to fetch the dom elements each time if you have complex selectors (which isn't your case, but still..)

Comment: Hey @PabloMescher, I understand in theory, but could you provide an example based on my code? Thanks!

Comment: There are no examples of selectors being used twice in your code, so my advice was actually off topic.. Feel free to ignore me if you already knew this :).
I was thinking under the assumption that there's more code in your app that manipulates the slider or combo-box, in which case it would be good to have them cached beforehand

```var $slider = $("#slider");
$slider.change(...)
// further down
$slider.on("click", ...)
```

Comment: @PabloMescher ah, i understand now ... I really appreciate the update, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else condition isn't checking the sqft and slider, it should be:

```
else {
    if ((condoData.sqft <= sliderValue)){
        $this.show();
    } else {
        $this.hide();
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwqkztn8/1/

Or, even simpler, that whole thing could just be:

```
$.each($('.condo-box'), function() {
     $this = $(this);
     condoData = $this.data();
     var sqftFilter = (condoData.sqft <= sliderValue);
     var bedFilter = (!bdrm1 && !bdrm2) || (condoData.bdrms == 1 && bdrm1) || (condoData.bdrms == 2 && bdrm2);
     $this.toggle(sqftFilter && bedFilter);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwqkztn8/3/

Comment: your simplification works, and has forced me to learn more about the .toggle method and expand my understanding of logical operators. thanks again!